# Manual Checkbox enable

Tags: winforms, powershell, combobox, event-handling

I have a `ComboBox` control on my form. What I want is when I change an item in the `ComboBox` from one to another, the event was handled. It is important that when changing and **not when choosing the same element**. All this time I used `ComboBox.Add_SelectionChangeCommitted($function)`, but soon I realized that the block that is also executed by the handler when the same (selected) item is selected from the list. A little digging in ComboBox events I am completely confused. Having tried several events (`SelectedItemChanged`, `SelectedIndexChanged`) I could never able to achieve the desired result.

An example of what I want to do and what should not be done several times when choosing the same element. When the block of code for Manual is executed several times, the contents of all TextBox are cleared, but I don’t want to.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize          = '420,240'
$Form.TopMost             = $false
$Form.FormBorderStyle     = 'Fixed3D'
$Form.MaximizeBox         = $false

$ComboBox                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox.width           = 391
$ComboBox.height          = 47
@('Automatic (DHCP)','Manual Input') | ForEach-Object {[void] $ComboBox.Items.Add($_)}
$ComboBox.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13,57)
$ComboBox.DropDownStyle   = 'DropDownList'
$ComboBox.DrawMode        = 'OwnerDrawFixed'

$Button                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.text              = "Set"
$Button.width             = 60
$Button.height            = 30
$Button.visible           = $false
$Button.enabled           = $false
$Button.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(336,126)

$CheckBox                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox.width           = 65
$CheckBox.height          = 15
$CheckBox.visible         = $false
$CheckBox.Checked         = $false
$CheckBox.enabled         = $true
$CheckBox.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16,210)

$TextBox1                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox1.Name            = "TextBox1"
$TextBox1.multiline       = $false
$TextBox1.width           = 40
$TextBox1.height          = 20
$TextBox1.visible         = $false
$TextBox1.enabled         = $true
$TextBox1.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(81,100)

$TextBox2                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox2.Name            = "TextBox2"
$TextBox2.multiline       = $false
$TextBox2.width           = 40
$TextBox2.height          = 20
$TextBox2.visible         = $false
$TextBox2.enabled         = $false
$TextBox2.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(81,208)

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($TextBox1,$TextBox2,$Button,$ComboBox,$CheckBox))

$global:ManualChecked = $null
$global:AutomaticChecked = $null

$ComboBox.Add_SelectionChangeCommitted($methodSelection)

$netwValues = New-Object 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
$methodSelection = 
{
    switch($ComboBox.Text) 
    { 
        "Manual Input" 
        {
            $CheckBox.Visible = $Button.Visible = $true
            $Button.Enabled = $false 
            ForEach ($control in $Form.controls) 
            {
                if ($control -is [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] ) 
                {
                    $control.Visible = $control.Enabled = $true
                    $control.Clear()
                    if($netwValues.Count -gt 0)
                    {
                        $control.Text = $netwValues.Item($control.Name)
                        $netwValues.Remove($control.Name)
                    }
                 }
             }
            if($global:ManualChecked -eq 1)
                        {
                            $CheckBox.Checked = $true
                            $TextBox2.Enabled = $true
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $CheckBox.Checked = $false
                            $TextBox2.Enabled = $false
                        }
        }
        "Automatic (DHCP)" 
        {
            ForEach($control in $Form.controls) 
            {
                if($control -is [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] -or $control -is [System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox] -or $control -is [System.Windows.Forms.Button]) 
                {
                    $control.Visible = $control.Enabled  = $true
                    if($control -is [System.Windows.Forms.Label] -or $control -is [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]) 
                    {
                        $control.Enabled = $false
                        if($control -is [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]) 
                        {
                            if($control.Text.Length)
                            {
                                $netwValues.Add($control.Name,$control.Text)
                                $control.Clear()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if($global:AutomaticChecked -eq 1)
            {
                $CheckBox.Checked = $true
            }
            else
            {
                $CheckBox.Checked  = $false
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just take a global variable and save current selected index in it on next event check for previous selected index, if it is different then do what you want to do

Comment: @Anil Isn't the point of event handlers that we don't keep a bunch of bool variables and check them every time?

Comment: @NikitaKobtsev Assuming that text on each of your elements in combo box is different you can use textchanged event on combobox. This event is not called for same elements but it will also not be called if different elements have same text:)

Comment: @Anil this is not how it works. When you change an item, the index / value changes (what you probably want to suggest) of the selected item, but not the text. I also thought that `SelectedValueChanged` would solve the problem, but no, in fact, the code block is executed twice, I tried.

Comment: Well when you change an item in combobox the text of combobox will also change and the will raise this event comboBox1_TextChanged, this event is only fired if and only if the text has changed, that being said it means that it will not called if you select the same item again but will not fire also if a different item with same text is selected. Also i do know that index / value changes when we select a new item but I particularly refered to text property change of combobox not index / value changes, I may still be suggesting that is not what you want but do let me know

Comment: @Anil Firstly, it doesn't work and will never work in that case. Secondly, have you tried it yourself? How the `TextChanged` event works: you're in the code or the user change the text of the element to another one and the event is triggered. **I'm not changing the text (!)**, but the element index from one to another. What you propose and what I'm using now sounds something like SelectedTextChanged (the meaning is the same as `SelectedValueChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted`, the only difference is that the second cannot be called programmatically, only by the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this logic yourself.

```bsh
# Simple class for using as item for combobox instead of just string.
class CbItem
{
    CbItem([string] $value)
    {
        $this.Value = $value
    }

    [string] $Value

    [string] ToString()
    {
        return $this.Value
    }
}

# Add instances of this class into combobox.
$ComboBox.Items.Add([CbItem]::new('Automatic (DHCP)'))
$ComboBox.Items.Add([CbItem]::new('Manual Input'))

# Create a variable for storing current combobox's item.
$global:CurrentCbItem = $null

# Add logic at the begining of handler for exiting if selected item is the same as the last one.
$methodSelection = 
{
    if ([Object]::ReferenceEquals($global:CurrentCbItem, $ComboBox.SelectedItem))
    {
        return
    }
    $global:CurrentCbItem = $ComboBox.SelectedItem

    ...
}
```